# Python data structures manipulations

Tags: python

I have file structure 'X' like below:

```
[u'2c91808654e491580154e88ba78b0bd3', 
u'2c91808654e491580154e88ba78e0bd4', 
u'2c91808654e491580154e88ba7930bd5', 
u'2c91808654e48e760154e88ba5a70b1f', 
u'2c91808654e48e760154e88ba5ab0b21', 
u'2c91808654e48e760154e88ba5ae0b24', 
u'2c91808654e48e760154e88ba5c10b25']
[]
[u'2c91808654e48e760154e88ba5a70b1f', 
u'2c91808654e48e760154e88ba5ab0b21', 
u'2c91808654e48e760154e88ba5ae0b24', 
u'2c91808654e48e760154e88ba5c10b25'
u'2c91808654e491580154e88ba78e0bd4']
[]
[]
[]
```

And then I have a list of items 'Y' like -

```
[u'2c91808654e48e760154e88ba5ae0b24', 
u'2c91808654e48e760154e88ba5c10b25'
u'2c91808654e491580154e88ba7930bd5', 
u'2c91808654e48e760154e88ba5a70b1f', 
u'2c91808654e48e760154e88ba5ab0b21']
```

I want to remove the items from X which aren't present in Y. Note: There might be multiple occurrences of same item in X at different places.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension.

```
z = [element for element in x if element not in y]
```